# Proper imports in an installable python project

Tags: python-3.x, setuptools

I'm trying to clean a python project on pypi to make it installable. It has the following structure (very simplified)

```
project_x/
  project_x/
    pack_a/
      __init__.py
      mod_a1.py
      mod_a2.py
    pack_b/
      __init__.py
      mod_b.py
  setup.py
  README
  ...
```

In `mod_a1.py` there is something like `from pack_a.mod_a2 import something`.
So I added, to the setup.py, the line `package_dir: {"": "project_x"}` for this to work.

However, `mod_b.py` uses relative imports: `from ..pack_a.mod_a import ...`.
This fails with
`ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`

What is the correct way to handle this? Avoid using relative imports? Writing full paths, such a `from project_x.pack_a import...` everywhere? Or something smart in the setup.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that `pack_a` (and its modules) assumes itself to be a top-level package, while `pack_b` (and its modules) assumes itself to be a sub-package of `project_x`.

You cannot have both. Instead, you will need to reconcile their implementation.

If you use `package_dir: {"": "project_x"}`, then both packages should use absolute imports towards each other (but internally they can use either relative/absolute imports). Please note that this option also means that `project_x` will not exist as an importable item, i.e. users will **NOT** be able to execute the following statements:

```py
import project_x
from project_x import pack_a, pack_b
```

If you remove `package_dir`, then any statement in the form of:

```py
from pack_a import ...  # => it should be from project_x.pack_a ...
from pack_b import ...  # => it should be from project_x.pack_b ...
```

will be wrong because `pack_a` and `pack_b` are not top-level packages.
Instead you could use relative imports, or fix the absolute imports to start with `project_x`.

Comment: Thank you. I thought so. So there is probably no hack (in setup.py) how to reconcile, for instance "omitting project_x internally" and "using project_x" when importing it outside the project? Probably no, just asking.

Comment: I am afraid not, what `setuptools` is doing is simply replicating the file structure you have in the disk inside the `wheel` which is later copied into your users machine, it does not change how the import system will work. To do something similar to what you are thinking one would have to hack into import hooks which is a non-trivial task: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html.